# Can't create new record via form in Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, postgresql

This form was working perfectly but I've not used it for a little while and I'm sure I've introduced an error somewhere, but I can't track what it might be.  I have two other similar forms that submit to the same postgres db as expected. I can edit an existing record ok, so looks like it is just the new/create method I'm having problems with.  The log doesn't actually show any error, it just redirects back to the new view:

```
Processing by CoffeeshopsController#new as HTML
  Rendering coffeeshops/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (1.4ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered partials/_mainnav.html.erb (10.2ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (1.1ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered coffeeshops/new.html.erb within layouts/application (22.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 155.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/coffeeshops/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=2A91tyxSfricbX03rLRcx9Vqm%2FuWQiZSgwwjmmScH3GrTe63RRBMTHs72%2F4cQaoXD5yC8jxY2GaRLgHvdhgCbg%3D%3D&coffeeshop%5Bname%5D=New+Coffee+Shop&coffeeshop%5Bsnippet%5D=Great+new+coffee+on+the+banks+of+the+thames&coffeeshop%5Bdesc%5D=lovely+coffee+shop+serving+Red+Brick+coffee&coffeeshop%5Barea%5D=central&coffeeshop%5Burl%5D=website.com&coffeeshop%5Bemail%5D=&coffeeshop%5Baddress%5D=&coffeeshop%5Bpostcode%5D=&coffeeshop%5Blocale%5D=central&coffeeshop%5Bphone%5D=123&coffeeshop%5Bimage_thumb_path%5D=photo.jpg&coffeeshop%5Bimage_path%5D=photo.jpg&coffeeshop%5Bbeans%5D=Red+Brick&coffeeshop%5Blong_black%5D=2.5&coffeeshop%5Btag_list%5D=tag&commit=Save+Coffeeshop" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 17:46:34 +0100
Processing by CoffeeshopsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2A91tyxSfricbX03rLRcx9Vqm/uWQiZSgwwjmmScH3GrTe63RRBMTHs72/4cQaoXD5yC8jxY2GaRLgHvdhgCbg==", "coffeeshop"=>{"name"=>"New Coffee Shop", "snippet"=>"Great new coffee on the banks of the thames", "desc"=>"lovely coffee shop serving Red Brick coffee", "area"=>"central", "url"=>"website.com", "email"=>"", "address"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "locale"=>"central", "phone"=>"123", "image_thumb_path"=>"photo.jpg", "image_path"=>"photo.jpg", "beans"=>"Red Brick", "long_black"=>"2.5", "tag_list"=>"tag"}, "commit"=>"Save Coffeeshop"}
  Rendering coffeeshops/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (1.4ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered partials/_mainnav.html.erb (11.6ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (1.2ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered coffeeshops/new.html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 162ms (Views: 159.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

*coffeeshop.rb*

```
class Coffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
  paginates_per 5
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, against: [:name]
  require 'acts-as-taggable-on'
  acts_as_taggable
  #acts_as_taggable_on :tag_list


  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :roaster
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops# just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :user
  has_many :bookmarked_coffeeshops# just the 'relationships'
  has_many :bookmarked_by, through: :bookmarked_coffeeshops, source: :user

  validates :name, :snippet, :area, :image_thumb_path, :image_path, :presence => true


  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]




    private
    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      slug.nil? || name_changed?
    end

end
```

*coffeeshop_controller.rb*

```
class CoffeeshopsController < ApplicationController
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "****", password: "****", except: [:index, :show, :favorite, :bookmarked]

def index

  if params[:tag]
    @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.all
  end
    @coffeeshops = @coffeeshops.order("created_at ASC").page params[:page]
end

  def show

    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.find(params[:id])
    @last3_coffeeshops = Coffeeshop.last(3)
    @commentable = @coffeeshop
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @locale_cafe = Coffeeshop.where(locale: @coffeeshop.locale)
    @fave_count = @coffeeshop.favorited_by
    @user = User.all
    @currentuser = current_user
  end

  def new
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.new
  end

  def edit
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.new(coffeeshop_params)

      if @coffeeshop.save
        redirect_to @coffeeshop
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def update
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.find(params[:id])

    if @coffeeshop.update(coffeeshop_params)
      redirect_to @coffeeshop
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def favorite
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.find(params[:id])
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @coffeeshop
      redirect_to :back, notice: "You favorited #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@coffeeshop)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Unfavorited #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Nothing happened."
    end
  end

  def bookmarked
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.find(params[:id])
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "bookmarked"
      current_user.bookmarks << @coffeeshop
      redirect_to :back, notice: "You bookmarked #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    elsif type == "unbookmark"
      current_user.bookmarks.delete(@coffeeshop)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "You removed #{@coffeeshop.name} bookmark"

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Nothing happened."
    end
  end


  private
    def coffeeshop_params
      params.require(:coffeeshop).permit(:name, :desc, :area, :url, :email, :address, :postcode, :locale, :phone, :image_path, :image_thumb_path, :snippet, :beans, :long_black, :tag_list)
    end
end
```

*the form**

```
<%= form_for :coffeeshop, url: coffeeshops_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Snippet %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :snippet %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Desciption %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :desc %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Area %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :area %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :URL %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :url %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Address %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Postcode %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :postcode %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Locale %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :locale %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :phone %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Thumbnail %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :image_thumb_path %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Image %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :image_path %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Beans %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :beans %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Price_of_long_black %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :long_black %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list, 'Tags (separated by commas)' %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :tag_list %>
<p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

*coffeeshop_params*

```
  private
    def coffeeshop_params
      params.require(:coffeeshop).permit(:name, :desc, :area, :url, :email, :address, :postcode, :locale, :phone, :image_path, :image_thumb_path, :snippet, :beans, :long_black, :tag_list, :image2, :image3)
    end
```

**Update**
Couldn't work this out so re-wrote the form in a new partial which works.

Comment: Please add the code for your view to the question. It seems like it may be an issue with the way you're building the form.

Comment: just added the form above.

Comment: Can you add the whole `coffeeshop_controller`?

Comment: Just added the params, which might be the issue.  I'm requiring two fields that are not in the form.  I'll remove and test.

Comment: Nope. that didn't solve it.

Comment: added the whole controller

Comment: can you see if there is a validation failing?.  One way to do this is to change `render new` to `render @coffeeshop.to_json` and post a request.

Comment: a better way to do this would be to add `<%= f.error_messages %>
` just under `<%= form_for :coffeeshop, url: coffeeshops_path do |f| %>` in your view

Comment: your request seems to be a `GET` and not a `POST`... why are you specifying the `url: coffeeshops_path` in the form?

Comment: @MichaelGorman it appears `<%= f.error_messages %>` was deprecated. 
@gabrielhilal I changed the form to `<%= form_for :coffeeshop do |f| %>` but hasn't solved it.

Comment: Have added `<% if @coffeeshop.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @coffeeshop.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>`

But not getting any errors at all.

Comment: I would be very eager to see the routes. Can update the question with that. Also try `<%= form_for @coffeeshop do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, based on your controller, your form is submitting fine but it is unable to save the record because of possibly validations, displaying the error messages on this page will tell you where your error is. My guess is unique constraints at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting using a GET request, according to your log:

```
Started GET "/coffeeshops/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=2A91tyxSfricbX03rLRcx9Vqm%2FuWQiZSgwwjmmScH3GrTe63RRBMTHs72%2F4cQaoXD5yC8jxY2GaRLgHvdhgCbg%3D%3D&coffeeshop%5Bname%5D=New+Coffee+Shop&coffeeshop%5Bsnippet%5D=Great+new+coffee+on+the+banks+of+the+thames&coffeeshop%5Bdesc%5D=lovely+coffee+shop+serving+Red+Brick+coffee&coffeeshop%5Barea%5D=central&coffeeshop%5Burl%5D=website.com&coffeeshop%5Bemail%5D=&coffeeshop%5Baddress%5D=&coffeeshop%5Bpostcode%5D=&coffeeshop%5Blocale%5D=central&coffeeshop%5Bphone%5D=123&coffeeshop%5Bimage_thumb_path%5D=photo.jpg&coffeeshop%5Bimage_path%5D=photo.jpg&coffeeshop%5Bbeans%5D=Red+Brick&coffeeshop%5Blong_black%5D=2.5&coffeeshop%5Btag_list%5D=tag&commit=Save+Coffeeshop" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 17:46:34 +0100
```

Because of this, Rails is routing the request to the `new` action in the controller, as the next line in the log says:

```
Processing by CoffeeshopsController#new as HTML
```

The crux of the problem is that your loading a generic symbol `:coffeeshop` instead of the object you instantiated in the `new` action.

Because you're just using a symbol and not an actual object, Rails doesn't know you want to submit a POST request.

Changing this:

```
<%= form_for :coffeeshop, url: coffeeshops_path do |f| %>
```

to this:

```
<%= form_for @coffeeshop do |f| %>
```

should do the trick.